# Async return Task method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

My method looks like this:

```cs
public override async Task ReceiveAsync(WebSocket socket, WebSocketReceiveResult result, byte[] buffer)
{
    string value = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);

    var message = Message.Create(value);

    if (message is CallMessage callMessage)
    {
        await OnCall(socket, callMessage);
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask; // ??? -> Does it require here?
}
```

If the code doesn't enter the if block, do I need to write `await Task.CompletedTask` at the end of the method?

Comment: No, the final `await Task.CompletedTask` is not required as the return type is effectively `void`.

Comment: The compiler returns the task for you when methods are marked as async

Answer (score 7):

No, you do not.

`await Task.CompletedTask` does exactly nothing.

Comment: "*does exactly nothing*" - Well, apart from generates a bunch more *CIL* i guess

Comment: @MichaelRandall: Good point. It's an *inefficient way* of doing nothing. :)